# I get an invalid ordinal error when reading from a database

Tags: database, vb.net

```
    Dim sqlCountQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM codes"
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim CountCommand As New MySqlCommand(sqlCountQuery, SQLConnection)
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = strServerString
    SQLConnection.Open()
    reader = CountCommand.ExecuteReader
    reader.Read()
    CodeCounter = reader.GetInt32(0)
    SQLConnection.Close()



    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM codes"
    Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, SQLConnection)
    SQLConnection.Open()
    reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()

    For b = 0 To CodeCounter - 1
        test = reader.GetInt32(b)
    Next
```

The top bit of code retrieves the number of codes currently stored in the database but when I move on to the second part with the for loop, it correctly retrieves the first code from the database, but after that I get an error saying "You have specified an invalid column ordinal.". I have been running it line by line which is how I know it retrieves the first code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the number of columns to the number of rows. `CodeCounter` is the row count but in second part of code you tried to get data from column. `reader.GetInt32(int)` gets data from given column.

All code written in a very bad. Examin this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) with example for information how to use `DataReader`. Article for SQL Server data provider but it can be helpful for you.